# Hybrid Mobile Application Performance Testing

Tags: android, performance

i am performance testing a hybrid mobile application using the dev tools (inspect element) performance section. It shows idle time out as 90% for most of my scenarios, but i am unable to find out the reason behind the idle time. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you just did that using the inspect element Right?

I just took the performance test and it's showing the idle time as in the below image as i was not doing anything inside that page
[image]